# Why do I get "ERROR in src/app/component.service.ts(9,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Http'." in angular?

Tags: angular, http, import, httpmodule

I'm using Angular 7, and I have this folder structure

```
src
    app
        app.component.css  
        app.component.html  
        app.component.spec.ts  
        app.component.ts    
        app.module.ts  
        component.service.spec.ts  
        component.service.ts
```

In my src/app/component.service file, I have

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ComponentService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/todo/';
  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  findAll(): Promise<Array<AppComponent>> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + "/list")
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as Todo[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
...
```

but I repeatedly get the import error

```
ERROR in src/app/component.service.ts(9,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Http'.
```

I'm including the HttpModule in my service, so what else am I missing to get this included properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you haven't imported the `Http` class that you're injecting in your constructor.

But instead of doing that you should know that since Angular 4.3 we got the `HttpClient` class as an improvement to the Http class.

You should import `HttpClient` instead of `Http` from `@angular/common/http`

ie,

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ComponentService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/todo/';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  findAll(): Promise<Array<AppComponent>> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + "/list")
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as Todo[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
...
```